# String Split, Merge, and Stack multiple columns

Tags: r, transform, tidyverse, stringr, strsplit

I have the following raw data that looks like this:

```
rawData <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), 
          Name = c("Company B; Company A; Company C", "Company A; Company D", "Company E"),
          Name_location = c("Company A (USA (Primary)); Company B (Japan(Primary)); Company C (Korea,South (Primary))", "Company A (USA (Primary)); Company D (USA (Primary))", "European (Primary)" ))


 ID    Name                              Name_location
 1     Company B; Company A;Company C    Company A (USA (Primary)); Company B (Japan(Primary)); Company C (Korea,South (Primary))
 2     Company A; Company D              Company A (USA (Primary)); Company D (USA (Primary))
 3     Company E                         European (Primary)
```

I need to transform the data to look like the below:

The Name_location field has the location data for each company in the Name field, however it can be out of order. Also, if there is only 1 company in the Name field, the Name_location field will just have the location whereas if there are multiple companies in the Name field the Name_location field will follow the syntax "Company (Location (Primary)); Company (Location (Primary))"

I need a way to isolate a company and its location as individual rows, identifiable by the ID.

```
 IdealData <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
                  Name = c("Company B", "Company A", "Company C", "Company A","Company D", "Company E"),
                  Location = c("Japan","USA", "Korea,South","USA","USA","European"))


     ID      Name            Location
     1       Company B       Japan
     1       Company A       USA
     1       Company C       Korea,South
     2       Company A       USA
     2       Company D       USA
     3       Company E       European
```

Looking to accomplish this in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `separate_rows`, we can extract the specific component with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rawData %>% 
   separate_rows(c(Name, Name_location), sep=";\\s*") %>%
   separate(Name_location, into = c('Name1', 'Location'), sep= "\\s+(?=\\()",
         extra = "merge") %>%
   mutate(Location = case_when(Name1 == 'European' ~ Name1,
         TRUE ~ trimws(str_extract(Location,
               "(?<=\\()[^(]+"))[match(Name, Name1)])) %>%
   select(-Name1)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     ID Name      Location   
#  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      
#1     1 Company B Japan      
#2     1 Company A USA        
#3     1 Company C Korea,South
#4     2 Company A USA        
#5     2 Company D USA        
#6     3 Company E European
```

Comment: can you walk me thru this ([^(]+)(?=\\s*\\(Primary)"))) portion in how r reads it? Or point me to a good resource for learning more on what different symbols mean for instructing how r should separate strings?

Comment: @Ellie The `([^(]+)` matches one or more characters that are not a `(` before the regex lookaround to match zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by the "(" and "Primary" substring.

Comment: thanks! Also, I noticed one error in this. The name_location column does not always go in the same order as the Name column so for instance row 1 Company B should be Japan and row 2 Company A should be USA. Can you show how to handle this ?

Comment: @Ellie I have a doubt.  For the last row, there is no 'Company'  in 'Name_location'. For such cases, how do you match

Comment: I think the other response might be the solution then, I do need it to handle these cases. I was hoping there was a more elegant approach than looping through the entries

Comment: @Ellie I meant if there is 'European' in 'Name_location', and there are multiple 'European', how do you match

Comment: ah I see. It would only ever not have a company name if there was only 1 company for that row, so in this case company E. It seemed your solution handled that fine, just not when they were out of order

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Company E should map to European and company D should match USA. But if you look at row 1 the raw data has names company b company a where the location data goes company  a company b.  The ideal data should have company b for id 1 match with Japan and company a for id 1 match with  usa. This is accomplished in the looped solution, but I was curious if there was a way to tweak yours to also do this

Comment: @Ellie Can you check my updated code and solution.  It gives the expected output

Comment: it works yes, but the name_location would not only be european. The only pattern to when the name is missing in the name_location column is when there is only 1 company, but it could be any company / location

Comment: @Ellie Can you please post as. new question with all the patterns so that it becomes easier t understand.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without packages and libraries, you can just loop through the entries and create a new data.frame:

```
rawData <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,2,3), 
                      "Name" = c("Company B; Company A; Company C", "Company A; Company D", "Company E"),
                      "Name_location" = c("Company A (USA (Primary)); Company B (Japan(Primary)); Company C (Korea,South (Primary))", "Company A (USA (Primary)); Company D (USA (Primary))", "European (Primary)" ))
rawData$Name = as.character(rawData$Name)
rawData$Name_location = as.character(rawData$Name_location)

idealData = list("ID"=c(),"Company"=c(),"Location"=c())
for(i in 1:length(rawData$ID)){
  print(strsplit(rawData$Name[i],";"))
  ncomp = length(strsplit(rawData$Name[i],";")[[1]])
  print(ncomp)
  if(ncomp==1){
    idealData[["ID"]]=c(idealData[["ID"]],rawData$ID[i])
    idealData[["Company"]]=c(idealData[["Company"]],rawData$Name[i])
    idealData[["Location"]]=c(idealData[["Location"]],strsplit(rawData$Name_location[i]," \\(")[[1]][1])
  }else{
    vcomp = strsplit(rawData$Name[i],"; ")[[1]]
    for(compi in 1:ncomp){
      idealData[["ID"]]=c(idealData[["ID"]],rawData$ID[i])
      idealData[["Company"]]=c(idealData[["Company"]],vcomp[compi])
      loc = strsplit(rawData$Name_location[i],";")[[1]]
      print(loc)
      loc = loc[grep(vcomp[compi],loc)][1]
      idealData[["Location"]]=c(idealData[["Location"]],strsplit(loc,"\\(")[[1]][2])
    } 
  }
}

idealData = as.data.frame(idealData)
```

Which gives the output:

```
> idealData
  ID   Company     Location
1  1 Company B        Japan
2  1 Company A         USA 
3  1 Company C Korea,South 
4  2 Company A         USA 
5  2 Company D         USA 
6  3 Company E     European
```